# No Buttons For Adminhtml Form

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, forms

I have created a form for my extension using [this](https://www.maximehuran.fr/en/layouts-and-forms-on-magento-2-admin/) tutorial.

My problem is that I have no buttons (save, delete, etc) in my actions bar.

I can add `Save and Continue Edit`, as the tutorial has, and this shows. However, the other default buttons are missing.

Below is my `Edit.php`:

```
namespace Wildcard\QuantityGroups\Block\Adminhtml\Quantitygroups;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Edit extends Container
{

    /** @var  Registry $_coreRegistry */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {

        $this->_objectId   = 'id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'Wildcard_QuantityGroups';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_quantitygroups';

        $this->buttonList->add(
            'save_and_continue',
            [
                'label'          => __('Save and Continue Edit'),
                'class'          => 'save',
                'data_attribute' => [
                    'mage-init' => [
                        'button' => ['event' => 'saveAndContinueEdit', 'target' => '#edit_form'],
                    ],
                ]
            ],
            10
        );

        if ($this->_coreRegistry->registry('quantityGroups_quantityGroup')->getId()) {
            $this->buttonList->remove('reset');
        }
    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        if ($this->_coreRegistry->registry('quantityGroups_quantityGroup')->getId()) {
            return __("Edit Quantity Group '%1'", $this->escapeHtml($this->_coreRegistry->registry('quantityGroups_quantityGroup')->getTitle()));
        } else {
            return __('New Quantity Group');
        }
    }

    protected function _isAllowedAction($resourceId)
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed($resourceId);
    }

    protected function _getSaveAndContinueUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('quantitygroups/actions/save', ['_current' => true, 'back' => 'edit', 'active_tab' => '']);
    }
```

Can someone please let me know what I am missing? I have gone through core extensions and other tutorials to see what I might be missing, but cannot find it!

I am using Magento 2.1.5.

Please let me know if I need to share more code.

Comment: if ($this->_isAllowedAction('Wildcard_QuantityGroups::save')) { can you remove that and check it

Comment: That didn't do anything

Comment: it is checking permission for that resource.

Comment: No, I mean removing it did not help. I know what the line does.

Comment: @sunilpatel Do you have any other suggestions? I really need to get this working

Comment: @Wildcard27 added my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code :

```
<?php
namespace Wildcard\QuantityGroups\Block\Adminhtml\Quantitygroups;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Edit extends Container
{

    /** @var  Registry $_coreRegistry */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {

        $this->_objectId   = 'id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'Wildcard_QuantityGroups';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_quantitygroups';

        parent::_construct();

        $this->buttonList->add(
            'save_and_continue',
            [
                'label'          => __('Save and Continue Edit'),
                'class'          => 'save',
                'data_attribute' => [
                    'mage-init' => [
                        'button' => ['event' => 'saveAndContinueEdit', 'target' => '#edit_form'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            10
        );

        if ($this->_coreRegistry->registry('quantityGroups_quantityGroup')->getId()) {
            $this->buttonList->remove('reset');
        }
    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        if ($this->_coreRegistry->registry('quantityGroups_quantityGroup')->getId()) {
            return __("Edit Quantity Group '%1'", $this->escapeHtml($this->_coreRegistry->registry('quantityGroups_quantityGroup')->getTitle()));
        } else {
            return __('New Quantity Group');
        }
    }

    protected function _isAllowedAction($resourceId)
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed($resourceId);
    }

    protected function _getSaveAndContinueUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('quantitygroups/actions/save', ['_current' => true, 'back' => 'edit', 'active_tab' => '']);
    }
}
```

You missed `parent::_construct();` line  in function `protected function _construct()`

Comment: Absolute legend. Thank you! I think I have been working on this for too long!

Answer (score 0):

Add following detail in your construct function.

```
 protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->buttonList->update('save', 'label', __('Save'));        
        $this->buttonList->update('delete', 'label', __('Delete'));
    }
```